# Union all same query twice returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that returns something like 'top' -> '30', 'metrictype' -> 'cpu usage'
(the query calculates the average CPU/MEM usage of the 20 percentile heaviest running machines.

```
SELECT   round(avg(avgcpuusage)) as 'top', metrictype
FROM    
    (  
SELECT (vmstatstemp.avgcpuusage),
    vmstatstemp.vmname,
    vmstatstemp.metrictype,
    @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar,  (select round(avg(vmstats.metricvalue)) as 'avgcpuusage', vmstats.vmname,
    vmstats.metrictype from vmstats   
    join vms on vms.naam = vmstats.vmname
    join klanten on vms.klant = klanten.ID
    where metrictype = 'cpu usage'
    AND SUBSTRING(vmstats.dataEntryTimestamp,4,7)  = date_format(now(),'%m:%Y')
    group by vmname
    order by avgcpuusage desc) vmstatstemp
    ) as temp
where counter < round(0.2* (@counter+1))
```

If I union this query with its own(see below), I get the following result:

'top' -> '30', 'metrictype' -> 'cpu usage'
'top' -> 'null', 'metrictype' -> 'null'

```
    SELECT   round(avg(avgcpuusage)) as 'top', metrictype
FROM    
    (  
SELECT (vmstatstemp.avgcpuusage),
    vmstatstemp.vmname,
    vmstatstemp.metrictype,
    @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar,  (select round(avg(vmstats.metricvalue)) as 'avgcpuusage', vmstats.vmname,
    vmstats.metrictype from vmstats   
    join vms on vms.naam = vmstats.vmname
    join klanten on vms.klant = klanten.ID
    where metrictype = 'cpu usage'
    AND SUBSTRING(vmstats.dataEntryTimestamp,4,7)  = date_format(now(),'%m:%Y')
    group by vmname
    order by avgcpuusage desc) vmstatstemp
    ) as temp
where counter < round(0.2* (@counter+1))


union all


SELECT   round(avg(avgcpuusage)) as 'top', metrictype
FROM    
    (  
SELECT (vmstatstemp.avgcpuusage),
    vmstatstemp.vmname,
    vmstatstemp.metrictype,
    @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar,  (select round(avg(vmstats.metricvalue)) as 'avgcpuusage', vmstats.vmname,
    vmstats.metrictype from vmstats   
    join vms on vms.naam = vmstats.vmname
    join klanten on vms.klant = klanten.ID
    where metrictype = 'cpu usage'
    AND SUBSTRING(vmstats.dataEntryTimestamp,4,7)  = date_format(now(),'%m:%Y')
    group by vmname
    order by avgcpuusage desc) vmstatstemp
    ) as temp
where counter < round(0.2* (@counter+1))
```

I do not understand why my result is 
'top' -> '30', 'metrictype' -> 'cpu usage'
'top' -> 'null', 'metrictype' -> 'null'
instead of 
'top' -> '30', 'metrictype' -> 'cpu usage'
'top' -> '30', 'metrictype' -> 'cpu usage',
can anybody explain this? (and make a suggestion on how to get the correct result?)

Comment: Use a different variable for the two subqueries.  This is probably a problem of when `@counter` is initialized.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
Your suggestion worked! Thanks a lot! Do you have any explanation why the same variablename causes this phenomenon (perhaps you should post your answer as a solution :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff pointed out: you need to use a different variable for the two subqueries